# esp-idf path doesn't override when esp-iot-solution repository is used

Tags: makefile, path, toolchain, esp32, esp-idf

I have cloned the [esp-idf-solution](https://github.com/espressif/esp-iot-solution#esp32-iot-solution-overview) repository and followed the instructions in readme.md file.

I already have esp-idf repository cloned before and can compile and flash successfully. But when I try to compile the new examples in esp-iot-solution it doesn't work.

```
$ make flash
Toolchain path: /opt/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc
Toolchain version: crosstool-ng-1.22.0-80-g6c4433a5
Compiler version: 5.2.0
Makefile:11: /home/abish/esp/esp-iot-solution/Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target '/home/abish/esp/esp-iot-solution/Makefile'.  Stop.
```

I have followed this step in readme.md `export IOT_SOLUTION_PATH=~/esp/esp-iot-solution`. This doesn't override the IDF_PATH. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like esp-idf is already included as a git submodule in the esp-idf-solution project, so you shouldn't have to separately clone the esp-idf repository (see https://github.com/espressif/esp-iot-solution/tree/master/submodule).

But make sure you tell git to clone the submodules from within the esp-idf-solution project.

```
cd /home/abish/esp/esp-iot-solution/
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Answer (score 0):

late answer but maybe helpful. I am beginner, so take this with caution. When you type in command prompt:

```
export IOT_SOLUTION_PATH=~/esp/esp-iot-solution
```

you are calling export.bat file in esp directory, but I think **export** is Linux command. Maybe you should type in command prompt:

```
set IOT_SOLUTION_PATH=%IDF_PATH%\esp-iot-solution
```

or

```
set IOT_SOLUTION_PATH=%IDF_PATH%/esp-iot-solution
```

or to add this line somewhere in export.bat file. Without this environment variable set, IOT solution cannot be used nor configuration cannot be done (idf.py menuconfig)

Regards